# Pass connection string from PHP to perl script

Tags: php, database, perl, database-connection

I wish to use a perl script on webserver to create some insert statements based on info coming from a port. I have PHP based website talking to db, I wish to find out how I can connect to the same PHP db connection through perl and log my insert statements while in perl script function. (Sorry I m new to perl and I didnt create that perl script.)

Comment: In order to give a more precise answer, you need to tell us more. Is your Perl script already creating SQL queries? Do you have the data? Do you want to know how to send that data to your database? Are you using mysql as we assumed, or something else? Please give us more details.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question, no its not already, its program given to me which I wish to use online but sadly its written in perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting to MySQL w/ Perl is pretty easy. Just use the same details that you're using w/ PHP, provided that both scripts are on the same server (or your DBMS accepts external connections).

```
use DBI;
$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:databasename:localhost", 'username', 'password');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same database with the same credentials, but not the same connection.

If you do not know the credentials, go into your php script and look for either the [`mysql_connect`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-connect.php) command or something more modern to create a db connection. I'm afraid I'm not familiar with that, so I cannot help you there. Take the server name, port, database name and username/password and use it with [DBI](http://p3rl.org/DBI) in your Perl program.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:db:hostname', $username, $password);
```

You can now use that `$dbh` database handle to insert data into your db, e.g. like this:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO my_table (foo, bar) VALUES (?, ?)');
$sth->execute('val1', 'val2');

# or more fancy, if you have an array ref with more array refs:

foreach my $line ( @$data ) {
  $sth->execute( @$line );
}
```

Comment: I see that you're a Perl guy so I'll cut you some slack :p Don't recommend the mysql_* functions as they're deprecated and don't support prepared statements etc. He should be using PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: I'm not recommending them, I'm merely asuming that his php stuff might have them, so it would be the place looking for his db credentials. Last time I used that stuff is a long time ago. If there are OOp modules available, those are probably great. ;-)

Comment: My bad. I should have worded that a little better because you clearly weren't recommending it. And yes, much better :)